# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, stored-procedures

I am getting this error while I am calling **store procedure** using **callable statement**.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
```

My code for this:

```
            Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
            CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call FILE_REPORT(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");
            java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(fileStatusReportRequest.getFromDate().getTime());
            callableStatement.setString(1, "2018-09-24");
            callableStatement.setString(2, "2017-09-24");

            callableStatement.setInt(3, offsetValue);
            callableStatement.setInt(4, fileStatusReportRequest.getSize());

            callableStatement.setString(5, "abc");
            callableStatement.setInt(6,  0);

            callableStatement.setInt(7, 0);
            callableStatement.setInt(8, 0);

            callableStatement.setInt(9, 0);

            callableStatement.execute();
```

Every time I am getting error at **callableStatement.execute();** line.

At store procedure side i am getting this parameter from spring side.

```
FILE_REPORT (IN fromDate DATE, IN toDate DATE, IN offset INT, IN limit INT, IN list VARCHAR(50), IN cId INT, IN aId INT, IN afeId INT, IN assiId INT)
```

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace? Additionally, since you are anyway using Spring Boot, you could use the `EntityManager` for calling a stored procedure query

Comment: actually i want to get more than one result list from store procedure so i need to use callable statement instead of entity manager. Entity manager does not support this(JPA)